# Cake PHP tree tutorial category list doesn't output properly

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm doing [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) tutorial and the output is different than what it says it should be.
It says I should get a nice nested bullet point list of categories.

**Instead I get this:**

```
/app/Controller/CategoriesController.php (line 7)
array(
    (int) 1 => 'My Categories',
    (int) 2 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fun',
    (int) 3 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sport',
    (int) 4 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Surfing',
    (int) 5 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Extreme knitting',
    (int) 6 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Friends',
    (int) 7 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gerald',
    (int) 8 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gwendolyn',
    (int) 9 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Work',
    (int) 10 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reports',
    (int) 11 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Annual',
    (int) 12 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status',
    (int) 13 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Trips',
    (int) 14 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;National',
    (int) 15 => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;International'
)
```

I followed the instructions to the tee.

Here is the CategoriesController.php file:

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        debug($data); die;   // line 7 in the error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have confirmed that you made it until the first intermediate test step. Now continue on with the tutorial, you are just at the beginning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that does not exist, the code's output is exactly as expected by the *test* code of the tutorial.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question - the problem is that the documentation is unclear, and this question arises from that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting is the expected output. The cookbook doesn't explicitly say you'll get a bullet list - it says "You should see something like this" and then displays a bullet list. It's misleading, I know...

In the source code, that method is described as:

```
 A convenience method for returning a hierarchical array used for HTML select boxes
```

So, your output is correct and the documentation is incorrect, or at least incomplete / misleading.

Comment: Well, misleading maybe. But it should be pretty clear to someone that a model method would never EVER return a bullet list (HTML markup), but an array of list elements. And by using `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` as indentation it should be also clear that this is used to form the depth inside each string.

Comment: Yep. Clear to someone with experience. Not clear to a noob, as this question illustrates. The documentation says you should "see something like this," and then displays a bullet list... that's confusing, especially to someone new to Cake and/or MVC.

Comment: Please suggest a correction to the documentation if you feel it is inaccurate/misleading.

Comment: I'll try to find the time to do that this week.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're confused about how to setup your view.
Your view to return an un-ordered list should like something like this:

```
    echo $this->Html->link("Add Category",array('action'=>'add')); 
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($data as $key=>$value){   
        echo "<li>$value</li>";
    }  

    echo "</ul>";
```

Don't forget to add this to your controller model :

> public $actsAs = array('Tree');